# Prove divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I prove divergence the following series?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{n}$$

what I tried

> by the sentence that if a series converges then the sequence limit is
> $0$,   let's assume by contradiction that $\sqrt{n}\rightarrow 0$ so
> $$\forall\varepsilon>0 ,\exists N\in \mathbb N,\forall n\in
> \mathbb N,n>N,|a_n-L|<\varepsilon$$
> $$|a_n-L|<|\sqrt{n}-0|=|\sqrt{n}|=\sqrt{n}>\varepsilon\Rightarrow
> > \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n}=\infty$$ therefore the series
> diverges

I feel like there is a problem in here

Comment: $\sqrt{n}\geq 1$ for $n\geq 1$, so it cannot tend to $0$.

Comment: You don't need to show that limit is infinite and you didn't show it. Negation of first line must be $\exists \varepsilon > 0 \forall N \in N \exists n \in N, n > N, |a_n-L| \geq \varepsilon$. Let take $\varepsilon\leq 1$, $n=N+1$, then $|a_n-L|=\sqrt{n} \geq 1 \geq \varepsilon$. Proven.

Comment: That every summand is at least $1$ is already enough to prove the divergence to $\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, so your idea for showing that the series diverges is a good one. Basically, if a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$. So if you can show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \neq 0$, then the corresponding series cannot converge. The idea is fine.

Now, your proof of divergence of the sequence $(\sqrt{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, on the other hand, is not quite right. You've tried to show that it doesn't converge to $0$. That's okay. Now, what you have to show is that:
$$\exists \epsilon > 0: \forall N \in \mathbb{N}: \exists n \geq N: |\sqrt{n}-0| = \sqrt{n} \geq \epsilon$$

Here's what you do. You know that these sequence increases. That is, you know that:
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \sqrt{n+1} > \sqrt{n}$$

So, let $\epsilon = 1$  and let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. Now, select $n = N+1$. Then, we have that:
$$\sqrt{N+1} \geq 1 = \epsilon$$
That finishes the proof. It shows that:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n} \neq 0$$

Now, if you want to prove that this diverges to $+\infty$, then that requires you to define what it means for a sequence to diverge to $+\infty$. I assume you haven't encountered that definition yet so I'm not going to harp on about it over here. Ask for it if you do want me to explain that.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is a bit all over the place, mixing inequalities in different directions here and there. I also don't understand why you are going for a contradiction. All you want to do is use the following result:

> Let $\{a_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers, and suppose that $$\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j$$ converges. Then $$\lim_{j\to\infty}a_j=0.$$

Now the **contrapositive** of this statement tells you that if $a_j\not\to0$, then the series diverges. This is what you want to use. Now since you seem to want an $\varepsilon-\delta$-type argument for $\sqrt{n}\to\infty$, let's do that real quick. Let $R>0$, and choose any $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $N>R^2$ (this is just using the Archimedean property). Then, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq N$ we have that

$$\sqrt{n}\geq\sqrt{N}>R.$$

This proves that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}=\infty\neq 0,$$

and so, using the result above, the series diverges.

Comment: It's actually okay, and typical, for people to phrase an argument via contraposition as a contradiction instead.

Comment: @MordeusMorgenstern Indeed, that I don't disagree with, but in this case the assumption that $\sqrt{n}\to0$ is never mentioned again past assuming it at the start, so it's not really a complete proof by contradiction either.

Comment: Yea that is fair